# Assigning virtual com port to physical com port

Tags: hyper-v, com

Okay quick break down of my situation, I have a virtual com port (COM5) that has data being passed to it remotely, I essentially just need the virtual port to mirror a physical port (COM4). So whatever data gets sent to com5 will forward onto com4 and back. Did not think this would be this hard to be honest. Turning into a nightmare. VMware unfortunately isn't an option either as I would have used that initially instead of going round in circles with this.

Any suggestions would be hugely appreciated. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: As you're saying you're going around in circles. What are you actually experiencing?

Comment: essentially I've tried to use a thirdparty software to create a piped com port from physical port on the machine to a virtual port on a HyperV machine. Didn't work. So the closest I've gotten is getting a virtual port on the physical machine. however this doesn't seem to help me a hell of a lot considering the PDT (PDE) that I need the information sent to is on a physical com port not the virtual one I've created.

Comment: As the dialog suggest to use a named pipe, did you try to explore that direction to see whenever you can make that work? While not a perfect fit, [Kernel debugging with a Hyper-V virtual machine](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/pavely/2013/06/25/kernel-debugging-with-a-hyper-v-virtual-machine/) would suggest you could run a script to do the redirection in a worst case.

Answer (score 1):

You could try Eterlogic VSPE (Virtual serial port emulator). It allows a lot of options and one of them is a port mapper that seems to do exactly what you need. It also has an splitter that allows to share a single COM between several applications. The license is free, at least for 32bit API.

http://www.eterlogic.com/Products.VSPE.html

Comment: will give it a go :) thank you very much and will post back with the results =D